# Maneira mais rapida de adicionar um item a um array, a usar uma estrutura

Tags: .net, array, vb.net, struct

```
Structure turma
    Public id_turma As Integer
    Public nome_turma As String
End Structure

Structure Disciplina
    Public id_disciplinas As Integer
    Public nome_disciplina As Integer
End Structure

Public Class F_Contentor
    Dim turmas() As turma
    Dim disciplina() As Disciplina

Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    turmas().id_turma.add(1)
End Sub
```

Tenho esse código. Um *array* de uma estrutura. Como faco para adicionar um 'item'? Não me esta a deixar da maneira que estou a fazer.

Comment: Você não pode usar `List` ao invés de array?

Comment: Tem que ser *array*?

Comment: Não, não tem de ser array. Mudei agora para lista mas da este erro:

Error 1 'id_turma' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Trabalho_mod_16.turma)'. C:\Users\AlunoP\Desktop\Trabalho modulo 16\Trabalho mod 16\Trabalho mod 16\F_Contentor.vb 69 25 Trabalho mod 16

Comment: A resposta à sua pergunta original está dada. Se agora está fazendo outra coisa e está dando outro erro, faça uma nova pergunta, dado o máximo de detalhes possível.

Comment: Vou fazer outra pergunta então. Obrigado pela resposta detalhada.

Comment: Cara, cria listas tipadas ai... faz uma classe com as propriedades que vc quer pra turma, e cria uma lista daquela classe, e seja feliz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe uma maneira rápida de fazer isso com *array* em VB.NET. *Arrays* não foram feitos para terem seu tamanho alterado. Se precisa fazer isto, é aconselhável usar uma [lista](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Se realmente quiser fazer isso, terá que [alterar o tamanho do *array*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Array_Resize__1___0____System_Int32_&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), o que fará uma cópia do antigo para o novo. Algo assim:

```
Array.Resize(turmas, turmas.Length + 1);
turmas(turmas.Length - 1) = 1;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Resize.vb).

Não tem razão para não usar `List` (que talvez tenha que fazer a cópia também, mas ele faz isso de forma mais inteligente que pode).

Mas se quiser usar *array* mesmo, tente minimizar o problema criando um *array* com tamanho suficiente para todos os elementos necessários. Se apenas tiver uma ideia do tamanho, crie um *array* que deve comportar todos elementos. Provavelmente será melhor ter um desperdício de espaço em memória para elementos não usados do que ter que ficar redimensionando o *array*. E tente redimensionar em alguns elementos de cada vez e não um por vez.

Se for fazer isso, aconselho fortemente ter um método que vá administrando a adição. Ou seja, que esse método verifique se tem espaço, se não tiver faz o *resize*. Este *resize* deve, idealmente, sempre dobrar o tamanho do *array* sempre que necessário. Deve iniciar com um tamanho razoável, 16, por exemplo.

Claro que o que estará fazendo é justamente o que o `List` já faz para você sem trabalho, sem risco de estar *bugado*.